Yahoo fantasy API oAuth2 not authenticating some users
I've been trying to help a friend fix an issue on his fantasy football website that collects data from a lot of places and gives you an all-in-one location. His issue is currently certain Yahoo accounts are able to get through and access the website while mine for example, can not. I click 'log in via yahoo' and it redirects me to the oAuth screen, I select yes, it redirects me back to the homepage and sends me 3 separate emails saying I logged in to his site. The problem is the log in wasn't successful and it only stays there.
Other platforms such as 'Sleeper' work without a problem. Here's the code:
export const HandleYahooAuth2 = (code) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
      YAHOO_CLIENT_ID,
      YAHOO_CLIENT_SECRET,
      'https://api.login.yahoo.com/',
      'oauth2/auth',
      'oauth2/get_token'
    );

    // Exchange authorization code for access token
    oauth2Client.getOAuthAccessToken(
      code,
      {
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        redirect_uri: OAUTH_REDIRECT_URL,
        scope: 'openid fspt-w'
      },
      async (error, accessToken, refreshToken, results) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error('Error getting access token:', error.data);
          reject(error);
          return;
        }
        console.log(accessToken)

        try {
          const resJSON = await MakeYahooRequest('users;use_login=1/games/teams', accessToken, refreshToken);
          const userArr = resJSON?.root?.fantasy_content?.users;
          const user = Array.isArray(userArr.user) ? userArr?.user[0] : userArr.user;

          const leagues = [];

          const yahooLeagues = Array.isArray(user.games.game) ? user.games?.game : [user.games?.game];

          for (const league of yahooLeagues) {
            if (league.code === 'nfl') {
              const teams = Array.isArray(league?.teams) ? league?.teams.team : [league?.teams?.team];
              const leagueId = teams[0]?.team_key.split('.t')[0];
              const leagueSettings = await GetYahooLeagueSettings(leagueId, accessToken, refreshToken);
              leagues.push(leagueSettings);
            }
          }
          console.log(leagues)
          resolve({ leagues, accessToken, refreshToken });
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error after getting token', error.data);
          reject(error);
        }
      }
    );
  });

Tried to adjust these settings with no luck
Getting this error as well when I attempt to log in with yahoo
He's reached out to Yahoo and hasn't been able to find documentation anywhere. How can I debug this more on my end for when the authentication doesn't go through?
Expanded version of errors

It appears you are getting a 500 error from your own system there, after the user has been redirected back to it, in the step where you are supposed to exchange the received code parameter for a token. So go and check what the error log has to say.

@C3roe I've added the expanded version of these two in the original post

That's still only what the browser console says, doesn't contain any information about the actual cause of the error. Go check what the server-side error log contains.
